# OData Data read- latest entry on top

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am using OData API to read data in my Fiori Application. The issue is, in Odata API, the latest data entry is at the end rather it should be at the top. How do i do that ie put my latest data on top.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$orderby` to decide what order the data is returned in. See [the docs](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-os-part1-protocol.html#_Toc372793696) for more info. This URL is an example of ordering (using the OData TripPin example service) that sorts by the LastName property:

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$orderby=LastName
```

We can use this same process to order by a DateTime value or an ID value to get your latest entries at the top. For example, here we order by the DateTimeOffset field `StartsAt` putting the latest entries first:

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People('russellwhyte')/Trips?$orderby=StartsAt desc
```

Comment: Thanks.. But i am already extracting the data using OData API and displaying it in a table using fiori. In my fiori app, how do i sort them from top (latest) to bottom(old) data entry.

Answer (score 0):

1)
As mentioned before, you might have a look at server side sorting using “$orderby” as seen [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/d2ce3f51e5e34198b0c1a7f6ddd98def.html).

2)
You might also want to check out the following tutorial on Sorting:

```
“
      items="{
         path : 'invoice>/Invoices',
         sorter : {
            path : 'ProductName' 
         }
      }"
```

We add a declarative sorter to our binding syntax.
As usual, we transform the simple binding syntax to the object notation, specify the path to the data,
and now add an additional sorter property. 
We specify the data path by which the invoice items should be sorted, the rest is done automatically.
By default, the sorting is ascending, but you could also add a property descending with the value true inside the sorter property to change the sorting order.”
Please see [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/c4b2a32bb72f483faa173e890e48d812.html) and [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough.25/preview)

3)
This here might also be helpful:
“In this step, we will create a button at the top of the table which will change the sorting of the table. 
When the current sorting state of the table is changed, the sorting state will be reflected in the URL. 
This illustrates how to make the table sorting bookmarkable.”

[Step 13: Make Table Sorting Bookmarkable](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/39759878ae4f48dcad0cf34da1d299f0.html)

[Sample: Navigation - Step 13 - Make Table Sorting Bookmarkable](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.core.tutorial.navigation.13/preview)

4)
These links here also look interesting:

[Sorting, Grouping and Filtering for Aggregation Binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/ec79a5d5918f4f7f9cbc2150e66778cc.html)

[Sample: Sorting](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Sorting/preview)

[Sample: With Sorting and Filtering Feature](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.UploadCollectionSortingFiltering/preview)